# Не могу получить JSON ответ с сервера

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, cors

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос к серверу, но возникает ошибка типа CORS Policy. Что я делаю не так и как получить JSON данные с сервера? При попытке сделать запрос с помощью PHP (Curl) отдает кусок сгенерированного html кода

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.wildberries.ru/webapi/product/65735329/data?stores=119261&ids=65735329&subject=6455&kind=0&brand=140686&_v=9.3.28.2&targetUrl=XS');

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')

    //xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.167 YaBrowser/22.7.4.957 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }

    xhr.send();
```

На PHP пробую делать так:

```
<?php


header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.wildberries.ru/webapi/product/65735329/data?stores=119261&ids=65735329&subject=6455&kind=0&brand=140686&_v=9.3.28.2&targetUrl=XS');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Когда открываю ответ в браузере, то он выглядит следующим образом, а когда пытаюсь спарсить, то получаю либо HTML, либо CORS Policy. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот список передаваемых заголовков в консоле Chrome.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с чего вы взяли (и откуда) что, делая вызов таким образом, вы получите JSON ответ, выполняя запрос откуда-то еще, а не с wildberries.ru?

Comment: Хотите сказать, что получить количество отзывов и покупок товара невозможно? Если минусуете, то хотя бы поясните, как бы вы это реализовывали. Думаю, будет интересно не только мне узнать, но и другим, кто столкнется с подобной ситуацией.

Comment: Нормальный вопрос Антоха, может и не всем прям нужен, он лично твой но он имеет место быть.Тут умников дохера которые не знают на каком месте выпендриваться. Вместо того чтоб помогать. Я вообще не понял почему если это апи, заходя по этой сылке просто в браузере она отдает страницу, а не какую то структуру данных. По идеи вбив ее в браузере должна вернуть данные.

Comment: Есть официальное API для [продавцов](https://openapi.wildberries.ru/), то что вы нашли - это внутреннее API, используемое фронтом сайта и только им. Тут остается только самостоятельно изучать какие запросы туда идут, по каким адресам и с какими данными, и использовать консоль браузера для работы с ним.

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов спасибо, Андрей, приятно, что остались ещё адекватные люди. Мне кажется, что они по какому-то параметру (из передаваемых) определяют, что за запрос и от кого он идет и, если он не удовлетворяет условию, то возвращают сгенерированный html, а если удовлетворяет, то JSON. Странная практика, конечно, ведь можно просто в JSON формате вернуть ответ о некорректности запроса. В общем странная ситуация.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в официальной документации я такого пункта не нашёл, сейчас собираюсь снова перечитать документацию, в надежде, что может просто упустил этот пункт при первом прочтении. Запросы в консоле выучил практически наизусть, других запросов на получение количества отзывов о товаре и количество их продаж, кроме указанного - нет, перепроверил несколько раз.

Comment: Похоже что да, раз у меня возвращает html значит у меня нет какого то ключа.Практика скорее всего не странная, а обусловлена  политиками ИБ. Сервис у них здоровый, и мало ли кто и что начнет досить, И попробуй разбери кто реально хочет данные а кто специально  чтоб нагрузить сервер. А так разделили на две ветки ,кто без ключа сразу на сервер статики и досвидос. А кто с ключом проходи в дом но мы еще будем смотреть чо ты тут делаешь. В принципе логику их айтишников понять можно.

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов чем-то оно точно обусловлено, сложно сказать наверняка, а этот запрос работает даже без ключа API. Нужно просто зайти на сайт, открыть консоль, зайти на вкладку Network, очистить консоль и открыть карточку товара, после чего в filter набрать data?stores и на открывшейся вкладке с Headers переключится на Preview, там будет JSON ответ.

Comment: ни фига себе мануал ))по просмотру json ответа.Так это тогда не api сервер, а просто страница сайта ,из потока которого ты хочешь забрать json. Ты что, парсер какой то пишешь?

Comment: Кстате вспомнил для браузеров есть плагин allow cors access-control-allow-origin plugin он позволяет обходить эти cors иногда

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов хотел, чтобы было понятно просто) Да, пишу парсер. Пока что обхожу с помощью chromedriver на python, но это жесть какая долгая история, хочется, чтобы это работало как-то пошустрее и могло крутиться на обычном хостинге.

Answer (score 0):

Из-за настроенной CORS политики на стороне сервера wildberries, ты можешь обращаться к API только с домена wildberries. Это можно обойти, если добавить к запросу дополнительные заголовки, их можно посмотреть, если перейти на wildberries и открыть консоль с запросами

Comment: Я пробовал добавлять заголовки, но что-то не срабатывает. Отредактировал вопрос и добавил скриншот с консоли. Что я упускаю? Отправляю заголовки: Content-Type, User-Agent, Accept, Referer, sec-fetch-mode, sec-fetch-site, x-spa-version